# Error al buscar una palabra en python

Tags: python

Tengo un codigo python para poder buscar una palabra especifica dentro de discord, pero tengo un problema qué cada vez que busco cualquier cosa relacionada con esa palabra aparece que existe esa palabra y no deberia de aparecer

Este es mi codigo:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
     
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
     
@bot.command()
async def botfn(ctx,  palabra):
    f=open("bots.txt",encoding='utf-8')
    libro=f.read()
    numero=libro.count(palabra)
    f.close()
        
    await ctx.send("**"+ palabra +"**" +   f"{numero}".replace('1',' Es un bot de FORTNITE✅').replace("0"," no es un bot de FORTNITE❌"))  
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")
         
bot.run('')
```

Dentro del archivo de texto "bots.txt" tengo una palabra llamada "StayHydrated41" y al escribir Hydra aparece y no deberia aparece escriendo ese texto

cual podria ser el error?

Muchas gracias! antemano

Comment: Lo que hace `count()` es buscar `substrings` dentro del texto, por lo que "StayHydrated41" contiene "Hydra" y por eso lo toma en cuenta. ¿Qué es lo que deseas buscar? Que la palabra sea exactamente igual a la introducida, incluyendo mayúsculas y minúsculas, o ¿De qué forma se validaría si una palabra es igual a la que deseas? Por ejemplo si tuvieras una palabra "Hydra123" ¿Se debería contar?

Comment: Sí, que la palabra sea exactamente igual a la que busco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor es usar expresiones regulares para buscar las coincidencias. Puedes utilizar esta [hoja de trucos](https://github.com/xcesaralejandro/regular-expression-cheat-sheet) para apoyarte en la construcción de la expresión.

Para utilizar expresiones regulares puedes utilizar el módulo [re de python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Hay algunos criterios que debes definir para encontrar la palabra, como si debe estar precedida por espacios u otros caracteres, la sensibilidad a mayúsculas-minúsculas, etc.
Te dejo un ejemplo que intentará buscar la palabra literalmente sin importar los caracteres a su alrededor.

```
import re

first_case = "holasoyStayHydrated41"
second_case = "hola soy Stay Hydrated 41"
third_case = "hola StayHydrated41, como estás StayHydrated41?"
fourth_case = "tayHydrated41StayHydrated41StayHydrated41StayHydrated4"

expression = "StayHydrated41";

print("First case: {}".format(re.findall(expression, first_case)))
print("Second case: {}".format(re.findall(expression, second_case)))
print("Third case: {}".format(re.findall(expression, third_case)))
print("Fourth case: {}".format(re.findall(expression, fourth_case)))
```

salida:

```
First case: ['StayHydrated41']
Second case: []
Third case: ['StayHydrated41', 'StayHydrated41']
Fourth case: ['StayHydrated41', 'StayHydrated41']
```

Este ejemplo devuelve las coincidencias de la expresión regular, pero puedes utilizar otras funciones del módulo `re` para aplicar la expresión según tus necesidades.
Las expresiones te permiten jugar indiscriminadamente con la búsqueda de textos, revisa la hoja de trucos (que es un resumen de todo lo que permiten las expresiones regulares) y ajusta la expresión según tus necesidades.